# C#: Attempting to create a shoe store: trying to evaluate the correct SKU

Tags: c#, if-statement, sku

I'm trying to create a shoe store program where the user will type in the SKU number to get the desired shoe. I'm trying to create an if statement that will ask the user for the quantity if the SKUs match or display "Enter a valid SKU: ", if it is invalid. Now it works but it automatically says that the number is invalid no matter what SKU I put in. Then when the entry is valid it no longer asks for the quantity!

```
while (keepBuyingShoes == true)
{
    // ask user for sku and quantity 
    int quantity = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter shoe SKU: ");
    String sku = Console.ReadLine();
    if (sku != s1.SKU || sku != s2.SKU || sku != s3.SKU || sku != s4.SKU || sku != s5.SKU)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid SKU number!");
       Console.WriteLine("Enter shoe SKU: ");
       sku = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else if (sku == s1.SKU || sku == s2.SKU || sku == s3.SKU || sku == s4.SKU || sku == s5.SKU)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter quantity: ");
      quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022)

Comment: You may consider debugging this by hand. Grab yourself a pen and paper, read through the code and write down input, variable values, and output.

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice how you use `||` in both `if` statements despite how one is supposed to be the opposite of the other? Isn't that strange? Shouldn't at least one use `&&` in that case? Huh.

So, yeah, as you might probably guess, your condition is wrong:

```
if (sku != s1.SKU || sku != s2.SKU || sku != s3.SKU || sku != s4.SKU || sku != s5.SKU)
{
    // ...
}
```

This is obvious if you actually think about the logic: you're essentially saying "if the SKU isn't `s1` or isn't `s2` or isn't `s3` or isn't `s4` or isn't `s5`...". In order for this to be false, the SKU would have to be *all of those* at once, which is impossible. So, it's a tautology. No wonder it's always entering that `if`.

The solution is to use `&&` instead:

```
if (sku != s1.SKU && sku != s2.SKU && sku != s3.SKU && sku != s4.SKU && sku != s5.SKU)
{
    // ...        
}
```

That way, you enter the `if` if the SKU is never any one of those.

And then you can just turn the following `else if` into a regular `else`.

Now, you should probably shove all those SKU objects into a collection and use things like `Any` and `All`, but that's a topic for another time.

Comment: When i used || it was based off the thought process that it would run through the whole list and recognize that none of them equal to the sku number causing it to print out "This is an invalid sku"

Comment: "none of them are equal" is equivalent to "not 1 _and_ not 2 _and_ not 3 _and_ ...".

Comment: Ok I see what youre saying now, but I've changed it around to your format and its still printing every input as invalid

Comment: Well, what's the input? Because if I test it with a valid input, [I get a valid message](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8kqHgR).

Comment: If you start out with an invalid input it will type invalid then once you enter a correct input it moves on skipping the quantity question and just asks would they like to buy more shoes. At first when I ran it when you'd type yes and ask to input another sku even when I typed in the correct one it'll come back invalid, but it's no longer doing that.

Comment: That's a different question from what you were originally asking. Well, you're gonna need another loop: as long as you don't have a valid SKU, ask again, and do so until you have a valid one.

Comment: For a little more formality of the rules regarding and, or, and inverting them, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple variables like `s1` , `s2` etc will not scale well. Everytime you add a new item like `s101` you are going to need to update your logic, which is not ideal.

You are better off using a collection like an array or list. Then you can query the collection via linq

Something like:

```
var skuList = new List<YOUR_SKU_TYPE>() {
    new YOUR_SKU_TYPE() {SKU = "SKU1" } ,
    new YOUR_SKU_TYPE() {SKU = "SKU2" } ,
    new YOUR_SKU_TYPE() {SKU = "SKU3" }
};

while (keepBuyingShoes == true)
{
    // ask user for sku and quantity 
    int quantity = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter shoe SKU: ");
    String sku = Console.ReadLine();

    //Check if sku matches one in our list
    if (skuList.Exists(x => x.SKU == sku)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter quantity: ");
      quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid SKU number!");
       Console.WriteLine("Enter shoe SKU: ");
       sku = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**NOTE** code is completely untested and might need some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

When entering an SKU into the console, it tests to see if it doesn't equal one of those shoe SKUs. If it isn't equal to just one of them, then the `else if` statement won't run. I spent some time dinking around with the code and found that this does exactly what you want (not including the object naming like s1...):

```cs
namespace TestStackQuestion           
{                  
    internal class Program         
    {

        public static string s1 = "SKU1";
        public static string s2 = "SKU2";
        public static string s3 = "SKU3";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your shoe SKU:");
            var UserSKU = Console.ReadLine();

            while (UserSKU != s1 && UserSKU != s2 && UserSKU != s3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid SKU \n Enter a new SKU");
                UserSKU = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (UserSKU == s1 || UserSKU == s2 || UserSKU == s3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter quantity: ");
                int quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```